# Difference between Vasicek and Gordy models

Tags: value-at-risk, vasicek, basel

I'm trying to understand what Gordy [1] added to Vasicek [2] model (the core of the IRB formula of Basel Accords).

Is it correct to say the Vasicek shows that the portfolio loss *conditional on $Y$* converges, by the law of large numbers, to its expectation $$p(Y)=\Phi\left(\frac{\Phi^{-1}(p)-\sqrt{\rho}\,Y}{\sqrt{1-\rho}}\right),$$
whereas Gordy says that, under their assumptions, even the (unconditional) portfolio loss converge to $p(Y)$?

That is, for Vasicek
$$L\mid Y\to p(Y)$$
whereas in Gordy
$$L\to p(Y)$$
or the latter result is already present in Vasicek?

I'm confused because the notation used in Vasicek is not perfectly consistent with what written in their text.

[1]: [Gordy, Michael B. (2003). A risk-factor model foundation for ratings-based bank
capital rules. Journal of financial intermediation 12(3), 199–232.](https://www.federalreserve.gov/pubs/feds/2002/200255/200255pap.pdf)

[2]: [Vasicek, Oldrich A. (2002). The distribution of loan portfolio value. Risk 15(12), 160–162.](https://www.bankofgreece.gr/MediaAttachments/Vasicek.pdf)

Comment: Gordy is more general (Vasicek is a specific model), focussing on portfolio invariance and granularity. The main contribution of Gordy is granularity adjustment. In Vasicek, you have a fine grained portfolio, Gordy shows what adjustment would be needed if the underlying exposures are lumpy, so in a way allows for quantifying name concentration risk.

Comment: Thank you, @Magic is in the chain! Hence Vasicek is one ASRF model whereas Gordy examines the ASRF models in general. But already in Vasicek there is the result that the idiosyncratic risks vanishes away and the (unconditional) loss is asintotically equal to p(Y)?

Comment: Correct but if it does not vanish in case the portfolio has a finite set of names with unequal exposures then there would be an expectation to add an adjustment (granularity adjustment), which is what Gordy is talking about in one of the later sections, and this then became the topic of another article that Gordy co-authored, and which kinda became the standard GA.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! If you would like to add an answer, I'll accept it.